# Layout template for interactive view (Border with inner Grid)

Tags: xaml, maui

I am working on UI and would like to know what is the best practice for building a dashboard like a view with boxes for an interactive dashboard. Currently my view is looking like this:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
            Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#3F0071">
      <Label Text="{Binding TotalMessages}" FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    </Border>

    ...

    </Grid>
```

However currently I am missing a text (Label) inside each Box (Border). Is it better to create inner Grid for that with two Rows or use `VerticalStacklayout`? Is there some way to create a template for layout to utilize it then later in all of the boxes? Should it be ContentPage with BindableProperties? I mean Border with inner Stacklayout or Grid with Label?

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I have also noticed an issue. In box on the left I am using VerticalStackLayout and in box on the right Grid. Can somebody describe why so? First chart is not visible and second one inside the Grid works fine? I have heard that Grid is using more resources and better to use Stacklayouts whenever possible? Here is my code:

```
 <Border Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#3F0071">
      <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10">
        <Label Text="Split 1" Padding="20,10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
        <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding SplitChart}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" LegendPosition="Right"/>
      </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>

    <Border Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#3F0071">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Split 2" Padding="20,10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
        <Chart/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have also noticed that setting height explicitly helps. Just trying to figure out where height should be attached in order to be set dynamically and not to some fixed value.

```
<Border Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#3F0071">
  <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10">
    <Label Text="Split 1" Padding="15,10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
    <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding SplitChart}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="200"
              TooltipBackground="Transparent" LegendPosition="Right"/>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Grid has some complex calculations(Row/ColumnDef and more) so VerticalStack would generally perform better, using ContentViews that are generic and take in strings to display is what I would do in your situation. I don't think using ContentViews would add any performance toll but you can verify that i guess

Comment: @FreakyAli VerticalStack is first thing came into my mind, however I am facing an issue with charts. Please see my edit to original question. With Grid everything seems to be fine, but VerticalStack is causing issues in chart being so small that there is only tiny line visible out of it.

Comment: are there any height/width/layout values set on Chart?  Its very difficult to say what might be wrong without any information like that.  For the 2nd question, yes you can create a re-usable control out of any piece of XAML.

Comment: @Jason thank you! I will update my question with chart properties tomorrow and drop a comment here. I will try to check for any width/height properties as well.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT sorry. There has been holidays in between. Now my question has been edited.

Comment: So what is the question now? Did you mean the PieChart under split 1 was missng?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT the question is still the same. While using Grid everything works fine. While using using VerticalStackLayout there is only tiny line visible from the chart until you set some fixed HeightRequest. However setting fixed HeightRequest sets limitations for resizing application window and scaling of Grid items.

Comment: You could create control template for your control. you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template)